# How to read a huge txt file to a ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatable, datagrid, observablecollection

I have an excel file which has more than 200,000 row. It takes more than one minute if I use OleDbConnection to read it into a datatable or ObservableCollection and then display it in datagrid. I change the xlsx to txt which is tab-delimited. I found it was very fast to put the whole txt file in the datatable. It takes less than 10s. I want to know how to do that if I put the whole txt to the ObservableCollection directly. It can't be done line by line since it will take more than one minute again.

```vb
'Define Product property    
     Public Class Product
                    Public Property Model As String
                    Public Property Opt As String
                    Public Property Description As String
                    Public Property Price As String               
     End Class

'define Products as ObservableCollection       
 Dim Products As New ObservableCollection(Of Product)()

'Read txt file to datatable
Private Sub LoadBound(ByVal fName As String)
Dim textLine As String = String.Empty
Dim splitLine As String()

CSVdata.Columns.AddRange({New DataColumn("Model"),
                          New DataColumn("Opt"),
                          New DataColumn("Description"),
                          New DataColumn("Price")})
                    CSVdata.Rows.Clear()

                    If System.IO.File.Exists(fName) Then
                        Dim objReader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(fName)
                        Dim contents = objReader.ReadToEnd()
                        Dim strReader = New System.IO.StringReader(contents)


        Do
            textLine = strReader.ReadLine()
            If textLine.Contains("""") Then
                textLine = textLine.Replace("""", "")

            End If
                            If textLine <> String.Empty Then
                                splitLine = textLine.Split(vbTab)

                                If splitLine(0) <> String.Empty OrElse splitLine(1) <> String.Empty Then
                                    CSVdata.Rows.Add(splitLine)

                                End If
                            End If
                        Loop While strReader.Peek() <> -1
                    End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: You already have an observable collection the DataTable.  Just bind to the DataTable or make the DataSource the DataTable.

Comment: There is no beginning to this loop. `Loop While strReader.Peek() <> -1 `

Comment: Sorry. I want to make it simple and forget to paste the beginning of the loop. I added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments and explanations in line.

```vb
Public Class Product
    Public Property Model As String
    Public Property Opt As String
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property Price As String
    'Add a parameterized constructor to your class to make coding easier
    Public Sub New(Mdl As String, O As String, Desc As String, P As String)
        Model = Mdl
        Opt = O
        Description = Desc
        Price = P
    End Sub
End Class

Dim Products As ObservableCollection(Of Product)

Private Sub LoadBound(ByVal fName As String)
    'Build a List(Of Product) from the text file
    Dim lstProducts As New List(Of Product)
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(fName)
    For Each line In lines
        Dim Props = line.Split(CChar(vbTab))
        Dim p As New Product(Props(0), Props(1), Props(2), Props(3))
        lstProducts.Add(p)
    Next
    'The constructor of an ObservableCollection can take a List(Of T)
    Products = New ObservableCollection(Of Product)(lstProducts)
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

```vb
Public Class Product
    Public Property Model As String
    Public Property Opt As String
    Public Property Description As String
    Private strPrice As String
    Public Property Price As Double
    'Add a parameterized constructor to your class to make coding easier
    Public Sub New(Mdl As String, O As String, Desc As String, P As String)
        Model = Mdl
        Opt = O
        Description = Desc
        Dim ParsedDouble As Double
        Double.TryParse(P, ParsedDouble)
        Price = ParsedDouble
    End Sub
End Class
```

To change the type of Price

1. Change the type of the Property
2. Adjust Sub New to get a double from the string. If the parse fails price will be 0.

   If you actually want a null (nothing in vb) see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/nullable-value-types

Comment: Awesome! This is 5x faster than datatable. I have one more question. I want to define price as double instead of string. If there are some cells in Price column in excel are empty, they are blank in txt as well. It shows System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.' How to handle it? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mary, you are great! I can get null and 0 by following your suggestion. They both exist in the data. One more question is there are double quote in the description in txt where the description has comma in excel. I managed to remove double quote after Dim strReader = New System.IO.StringReader(contents) in my original code (I edited my post, you can have a look.) but failed to do that in lines, line or Pros(2) in new code. Do you know why?

Comment: Your `.Contains` is looking for a substring of 4 double quotes in a row. Did that really exist in the source string? The string value looks like """"Hello""""?

Comment: Hi Mary, it is """", please see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2a91d280-7d62-43cb-8b41-4e7bb809ec95/using-double-quotes-in-strings?forum=smallbasic  I define a new string = line and can remove double quote. Don't understand why I cannot remove directly.

Comment: Hi Mary, hope I can find you. I want to check with you is there a same method to read a .mdb file quickly as you taught me to read a txt file. Now the file changed to mdb. The format is the same. I can only use OleDbConnection to access it. I expect to load the data more quickly.

Comment: No, sorry. An .mdb file is a binary file, not a text file. It can't possibly be the same format. To read an .mdb file you will need ADO.net and the OleDb provider.